# How to know dynamically if the loaded class is application class?

Tags: java, classloader

I am in a situation that I want to do some rewriting on loaded,i.e., currently running application class. I do not want to rewrite loaded library class. Thus I need to sort of filter the rewriting based either on the type of the class, being application or none application class, or another way I could do it is by checking the ClassLoader and see if it is of Application Class type.

To give some context let's assume I have the following code

```
    URLClassLoader urlcl = new URLClassLoader(cp);
    Class c = urlcl.loadClass(_className);
```

Assuming that `_className` is the current running class, that was intercepted by a listener, how can I know if this class `c` is an application class or not?

Much appreciated!

Comment: If I remember correctly java has an operator called instanceof to check if a class is specific type which is usually for polymorphism

Comment: @Nina: `instanceof` works on _instances_ of a `class`, not the `Class` `Object` itself.  The `Class` `Object` does have a `asSubclass` method.  So you could use `c.asSubclass(Application.class)`, which will throw a `ClassCastException` if it is _not_ a subclass of `Application`.

Comment: @user2478398, thanks, i tired that but seems that there are multiple implementation for ```Application.class``` which implementation should I be using? I tried to use the one from ```com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.Application```, but didn't quite work. That is, an exception was raised when indeed the class that I used is an application class. Perhaps I am using the wrong implementation?

Comment: @Inquirer: Whichever one you're referencing in your question.  Unless by 'application class' you meant something different (like, it came from _my_ application).  In which case, there are different things you can use to check.

Comment: @user2478398 No reason to deal with `ClassCastException`, just use [`Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)).

Comment: @Slaw: Yep, that's a better solution.  That'd be `Application.class.isAssignableFrom(c);` for anyone looking to use it (just to avoid any accidental order flipping which can happen a lot for stuff like that...).

Comment: @Inquirer You're apparently using JavaFX (which you did not specify in your question). In JavaFX there is only one public "application class": `javafx.application.Application`.

Comment: The JVM doesn’t know a concept like “application class”. You have to define what it means and once that has been clarified, it likely will be easy to check a class for those properties.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure of what do you mean by application class, but those hints still might be helpful.

You can simply check if one class is subtype of another with:

```
public static boolean is1stSubTypeOf2nd(Class clazz1, Class clazz2) {
    return clazz2.isAssignableFrom(clazz1);
}
```

If you would like to check if the class belongs to some package (to check if it is the class from standard API, third party library or not), you can use:

```
public static boolean isInPackage(Class clazz, String packageName) {
    return clazz.getPackageName().contains(packageName);
}
```

Further the standard API is able to provide you an info about all super classes of given class.